# How to align a cluster of points?

Tags: modeling

If you have a cluster of points selected like this:

[image: UV sphere]

how do you align the points so that they create a flat plane?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

You can achieve this by scaling the points along a perpendicular (Normal) axis:

Via Keyboard:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>: Change Transform orientation to `Normal`
- <kbd>s</kbd>: Scale selected
- <kbd>z</kbd>, <kbd>z</kbd>: The axis to scale on; the first 'z' specifies the global axis. Pressing again specifies local.
- <kbd>0</kbd>: The amount to scale by
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>: Confirm the action

Via Mouse:

[image]

Then you need to left click anywhere in the scene to confirm and modify the properties of the tool.

[image: Change Resize properties]

And you will get all the points aligned.

[image]

Comment: You can do this of course also just in global space, instead of normal, or any other. If you press the axis letter only once, you'll be in global, pressing the axis letter twice makes scaling use the selected transform space (view, local, gimbal, normal or stay in global if that's selected). What you end up choosing depends on what you need, of course.

Comment: Note this is also doable with the *Loop tools* addon

Answer (score 12):

If you scale the vertices to 0 along a specific axis, you can make them flat. For example, if you want to flatten some vertices along the X axis, you would press <kbd>S</kbd> (to scale) > <kbd>X</kbd> (for the X axis) > <kbd>0</kbd> (to scale them to zero).

Comment: How come when i do this, they moved, but my vertices aren't 0, they're stubbornly at 0.02124?