# Hiding all but the selected objects?

Tags: 3d-view, shortcut

I was doing my best to follow this tutorial from the Blender Guru, but, alas, 8 minutes in I've run into a real spot, a few moments after this [spot in the video](http://youtu.be/Xbc3KMIOuKM?t=8m59s).

I can only hide the selected, not hide all *BUT* the selected.  (Edits then effects ONLY the selected vertices.)  I know, there is a way to invert selection, but it doesn't look like he does this.

Also, what does he mean do he says, "This is not perfectly aligned..."

Answer (score 47):

You can hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>, this works for all areas of blender which support hiding (editmode, uv-editing, sequencer... etc).

In Blender, if you know the the basic action a key is assigned to such as (hide <kbd>H</kbd>), you can try different combinations with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd> to often perform the inverse.

Comment: I tried this, and it's great, there's just one problem - how do you unhide all, once that you're done? Tried Shift, Ctrl and Alt +H, didn't help...

Comment: unhide is **Alt** + **H**

Answer (score 23):

For completeness; you could also switch the *View* from *Global* to *Local* by pressing <kbd>Numpad</kbd>-<kbd>/</kbd> for selected objects. 
This is also accessible from the *Menu: View>Global/Local*.

[From the documentation:](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/Global_or_Local_View)

> Note that the layer and lock buttons on the 3D View header disappear
>   while in local view.

Answer (score 6):

He manually selects the bottom of the glass with *border select* (<kbd>B</kbd>) and then hides it (<kbd>H</kbd>), then does the same for the edge loop above.

Note that he has *Screencast keys* enabled, so you can see exactly what he does:

[image]

<kbd>A</kbd>: Deselect all

<kbd>B</kbd>: Border select

<kbd>H</kbd>: Hide

---

For flattening the mesh, he does <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> to set everything selected to the same position along the Z. See [How to align a cluster of points?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/140/599)

Answer (score 3):

Other guys have shared you with some very nice tips on **hiding**. However, I want to point out the key problem that is puzzling you now.

- Andrew didn't "hide all BUT selected". In fact, he just simply hided all vertices on that circle loop by hitting <kbd>H</kbd>. The reason why it appears that everything else was hidden is:

  1. He didn't show the complete view of the whole bottle during the following seconds. In fact, the top of the bottle is still there. You can confirm it around **`08:53`**.
  2. Furthermore, when in **Edit Mode** with **Wireframe** display, the Subdivision results generated by SubSurf modifier will be always shown, regardless the visibility of elements on the base object. That's why you cannot see them anymore after he hit <kbd>Z</kbd> to switch to **Solid** view.
- About your last word, I didn't notice he ever said anything like "This is not perfectly aligned..." Can you provide the exact moment in that video?