# Straighten Vertices Along a Line

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

On a line, I need to line up the bottom vertex points in relation to a top reference vertex point. How could I reset the X Y and Z coordinates of these vertex points to essentially line them up all through use of the vector of the reference point vertex.

I do not have access to Mesh -> Transform -> Scale on Axis for aligning vertices along a line.

Comment: related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28063/straighten-edges-not-on-axis

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/140/599

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could select one vertex, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, 'cursor to selected', then <kbd>.</kbd> (to transform with respect to 3d cursor), select all vertices, <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then <kbd>X</kbd>,<kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd> and then <kbd>0</kbd>

Answer (score 31):

## Align to a custom Transform Orientation

### 1. In Vertex Select Mode, draw an edge

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+LeftClick to create and then extrude vertices.

Then with the entire edge selected, snap the Cursor to Selection using <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>

[image: Create an edge for a custom Transform Orientation]

### 2. Create a custom Transform Orientation from the edge

With the edge still selected, click the "**+**" button in the Properties Shelf under the Transform Orientations panel.

[image: Create a custom Transform Orientation]

### 3. Select it for use

Click the Transform Orientation button which is by default set to "Global" and choose "Edge".

[image: Select the custom Transform Orientation for use]

### 4. Scale along it

You can now hide (<kbd>H</kbd>) or delete (<kbd>X</kbd>) your guide edge.

Select the vertices you want to align.

Set your Pivot Point to "3D Cursor".

Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) and constrain to your custom Transform Orientation by double-tapping an axis key (<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd>, or <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>). Then type "0".

[image: Scaling along a custom Transform orientation]

Comment: @brasshat This may be of interest to you. I had originally authored this as part of an answer to another question, but that question has since been marked as a duplicate and I think this answer actually more specifically addresses this question.

Comment: This is the answer that really helped me and i've used.

Comment: @kimholder Glad you found it helpful!

Answer (score 6):

One way to align vertices is to use the scale tool. First, with the properties shelf of the 3D viewport open, select the vertex you wish to align *to*, and copy the value of the parameter you wish to align to from the appropriate information button in "transform" pane at the top of the properties shelf. In the illustration below, I will be aligning the vertices along the y axis with the selected vertex. The value I will copy is in the green box.

[image: Vertex align 1]

Now, select all of the other vertices you want to align, and scale them to the value "0" on the axis you want to align them to. This will line all of the vertices up in a single axis perpendicular to the desired axis.

[image: Vertex align 2]

Then, with all of the vertices you wish to align still selected, in the transform panel, insert the value you copied from the vertex you wish to align to into information bar for the desired parameter (the one enclosed in the green box in the first illustration. If you want to align the vertices to two axes, repeat the process for the second axis.

This technique does not work quite so well if the vertices are to be aligned to an edge which does not parallel one of the x, y, or z axes. In that case, the quickest way I know to do it is, if necessary, to define the edge to which I want to align the vertices by defining the other end, and creating the edge, then looking from a view perpendicular to that edge, to align the vertices manually moving them with the <kbd>G</kbd> key until they line up the way I want them. When there have been a great number of points to align, I have also sometimes had success creating a plane through the two vertices, turning on snapping, and snapping the vertices to the plane, but in my projects, this usually takes too long to set up, and it's faster to do it manually.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of doing it. It may be similar to some of the other answers, but I found them difficult to follow, so here is a step-by-step guide.

Select the line of vertices. If all vertices are connected, hold Ctrl and select the first and the last vertex. If not connected, use Shift to add multiple vertices.

[image]

Press S, then X, then 0, and drag the mouse until the vertices stop changing

[image]

Do the same for the Y-axis (S, X, 0, and drag until no more change).

[image]

Then align to the desired vertex by LMB click and hold on the green arrow, dragging to the desired vertex, and releasing when the snap symbol appears

[image]

Do the same for the red arrow

[image]

Comment: The simplest one and my favorite way.

Comment: I think this only works if the axis you want to align the vertices to, is equal to the global/local/view axis. Would this work to align the vertices to an arbritrary vector(x1,y1,z1, x2, y2, z2) of 2 points ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plane and Apply Boolean to remove the excess lengths.. The boolean modifier applies things like NOT OR AND etc so you can isolate certain parts out and draw an plane aligned set of vertices on your shape using a plane.

[image]

A regular sphere with a lot of verts.
[image]

The knife plane of awesome! (just a plane, nothing to see here)
[image]

Note that this is in Modifiers for the sphere
[image]

Make sure to get the settings right as you need!
[image]

The resulting not so sphere anymore.
[image]

Apply the modifier and its chopped and aligned!
Just like cutting an onion just .. well no tears involved.
Keep experimenting and Have fun!

Comment: Please edit your answer, as it seems you're taking images from another answer/post or tutorial. I suggest you link the image to the proper site. A cleanup of this answer is necessary.

Comment: Please do not put text like that in images.