# Moving multiple vertices in a model

Tags: modeling, workflow, transforms

I was wondering how to move groups of vertices along a line. This picture shows what I want to do:

[image: model and target shape]

I want to move the vertices and edges inside the dark black line so that they are flush to the thick line. if anyone knows a macro for this please post it here.

Comment: You can probably cut this in half and then use the skrinkwrap modifier to stick that half to the other (thick line) surface in the y direction (your green line).

Comment: Please clarify.  Are the terms dark black line .... thick line ... the same? I assume the orange line is NOT a desired shape.

Answer (score 1):

The original object can have a Shrink Wrap Modifier added. Later you may choose to press the Apply Button or Apply as Shape Key.

[image]
Objects and Outliner above.

[image]

Original yellow object with Shrink Wrap Modifier not visible in 3D View in the image above.

[image]

Original yellow object with Shrink Wrap Modifier visible 3D View in the view above.

[image]
The vertex group selected in the image above.

[image]

The target of the shrink wrap.  Cube Scaled on X axis in edit mode with Mirror Modifier and Empty placed at center.  You can be more artistic.

Comment: For more adventure see this http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43903/is-there-a-way-to-move-multiple-vertices-to-be-aligned/43918#43918