# Create slanted end at a pipe / cylinder by Rotation

Tags: modeling

I have a cylinder here.

[image: the cylinder]

And I want to rotate its end vertices along Y to create something like a Bamboo with a slanted end like in this image:

[image: what i want to create]

But trying to rotate them, the cylinder's diameter gets shortened at the end and the face turns into an oval from a circle. I want the entire cylinder to be of same diameter until the very end face, which should be slanted and yet circular.

[image: how it appears]

Can this be done by using rotation at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why use rotation when it doesn't do what you want?

As an alternative, you could use the *Bisect* tool.

1. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
2. Press *3D view > Tool Shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd>) *> Mesh Tools > Bisect* and cut a diagonal line through your mesh.

   Note that your view angle and perspective matters; make sure you are in side view (<kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>) and orthographic perspective (<kbd>Numpad 5</kbd>)
3. Scale (<kbd>S</kbd>) on the Z axis to tweak the angle further

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Use the *[Shear](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/transform/shear.html?highlight=shear)* Transform.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd> to set the axis.

Answer (score 5):

**Shrink Wrap Modifier**

[image]

The vertices are projected in the Z direction where they meet the yellow plane.  This modifier is interactive when you rotate the plane.

Top vertices are placed in a vertex group called GroupZ.  You may press apply to make permanent.

[image]
Modifier active. Image above.

[image]

Modifer Not active. Original Shape. Image tilted to show plane.

[image]

In case you need to recover from a rotation W Smooth Vertex is ready.
The Z axis is restricted in the panel.  The Smooth Vertex changed the mesh marked with an arrow to the mesh in edit mode.

There is the extensive post here at BSE of many different ways to align vertices.  Including orientations.  I may search for it.

¿¡ This post by other authors is amazing !?

[Is there a way to align multiple vertices to another vertex?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43903/is-there-a-way-to-align-multiple-vertices-to-another-vertex/43918#43918)