# What's The Best Way To Create These Objects And Match Them To Another Object (References Inside)

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

Primary

I have created some beams that are next to each other.  I have not been able line them up exactly to my standards.

How can I match the shape to the size of the vertical post and have it rest against the post without it clipping? How can I match the shape to the size of the vertical post and have it rest against the post without it clipping?

Secondary

I'm currently following a [Stylized Well Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OlnkGCdtGEw) and the homework before part 2 is to create the wooden structure that goes around the well, not including the rope, roof tile, or the ground below.

It looks like I can get it all done with just using cubes, but I started with the roof supports and I'm having a bit of trouble.

I will post photos below to supplement my explanation. So I started by stretching my cube (G) and adding a slight bevel. I then inserted a loop cut in the middle and pulled it down to bend the shape. I then lined it up with the vertical posts and grabbed the corners of the face up against the post to match the width. I then rotated the shape downward and moved it back against the post, rotating the face to sit flat with the vertical post. However, I can't seem to line them up perfectly as they look crooked and keep clipping into the vertical posts.

Am I creating these shapes in the most efficient way? How can I match the shape to the size of the vertical post and have it rest against the post without it clipping?

[Photos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OI4rB.jpg)

Comment: Please place your images directly in the question.  Some readers want to see your text and images together.  It gives a sense that you want to make the readers experience easier.

Comment: Are the beams the subject of an extreme closeup ? If your image or animation is not focusing on the placement of those beams then ... I think the placement is acceptable for a simple project.  Otherwise I suggest you see video tutorials on Snapping, and Shrink Wrap and Object Shrink Wrap

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for all your help. New to Blender and new to StackExchance. I'll take a look at those tutorials.

Comment: Here is perhaps a related question.  You have final judgement on that. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43903/is-there-a-way-to-align-multiple-vertices-to-another-vertex/43918#43918

Comment: There plenty of human made buildings in the world that are not perfectly aligned. Perhaps all of them.  When you drop your cell phone,  it is also probably less perfectly aligned.  Plenty of humans limp because they are not perfectly aligned.  There is also the more difficult topic of transform orientation.  I would probably suggest you see such topics in a relaxed mood.  They are only one of the 999 topics you might see in any 3D Tool.

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 1):

There probably  isn't a best way, but sometimes it's easier to start this kind of thing in the flat, to keep things simple early on.

Using that approach, with Pivot set to 'Active Element', Vertex Mode, starting with a plane. and the right vertex active. <kbd>Numpad</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> Looking orthographically down Z

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> rotate a copy of the plane out to the desired angle.
- <kbd>K</kbd> with <kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Z</kbd> cut through with a constraint to the vertical
- Face Mode, <kbd>X</kbd> delete the unwanted triangle
- <kbd>E</kbd> extrude all the remaining faces
- Edge Mode, all selected, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> bevel the edges

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In order for the post to be the same size and be as one unit without clipping, boolean union, is required. Though for this project, it looks unnatural to have perfectly sized items.  I made mine smaller when I did it. But if keeping the same size, just bevel the ends and put nearly all the bevel except a small amount in the hidden inside of the stand, that will leave a small crack for realism.  Trees don't grow in one furniture piece, but for low poly, boolean modifier, Union choice, but don't "apply" unless needed later for other modifiers.

ctrl+j after to join as one object if using boolean etc.
You may know this anyway though.