# Straightening the sides of this mesh

Tags: vertices

I'm having difficulty straightening up this mesh in Blender - see here for the object:

[image]

[image]

I'm trying to follow the accepted answer [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33525/straighten-vertices-along-a-line) but I can't quite get all the vertices I need in order to straighten up the side. When I scale the object along the z index, in 3JS, the arc of the sides is exacerbated which is undesirable.

Any ideas on this?

**EDIT**

An example of what happens when it gets scaled in 3JS

[image]

Comment: How exactly are you trying to straighten the object? All of the sides look flat when I opened the file. Are you trying to make the sides vertical?

Comment: @Brenticus  I'm scaling the object in 3JS which causes it to distort which is why I need them to be absolutely vertical - see my edit for a what it looks like when scaled

Answer (score 1):

Go into Edit mode.  Click the vertex-select icon.

Press <kbd>C</kbd> for circle select.
Color in a couple vertices you want to align, then right-click.

Tap <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, then X, Y, or Z to limit along one axis.
You have to decide which axis is best.
Then press <kbd>0</kbd> to zero out that axis.

If you notice movement along the wrong axis, no worries,
just click X, Y, or Z at this point to affect another axis instead.
Tap <kbd>Enter</kbd> to finalize command.

Repeat with each pair of vertices 'till complete.