# how do i make a ramp around a corner?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, polycount

[image: ramp going around corner]
how do i curve a ramp around a corner like this?
whenever i try something, it's just frilly.

is there any good method to do this?

EDIT: people didn't understand, so here:[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it's very clear, could you please explain again?

Comment: i want a ramp to go around a corner, and stay smooth.

Comment: I appreciate your adding a screenshot but I have to admit I find it extremely confusing.  A simplified diagram or two that eliminates extraneous elements would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Make an auger, (see below) and scale to suit.

Delete the sections you don't want.

Extrude it's ends to provide entry/exit platforms.

Extrude all vertices down in the Z axis for thickness if necessary.

(the cylinder at center is optional)

Auger Blade -
-========-

Add a Curve path, leave it a, straight line.

Add the "Screw" modifier.  The bezier will turn into a solid disc.

Increase the "Screw" slider to watch the  Auger forming up.

Increase the "steps" to improve the circumference curvature.

Use ATL-C in Object mode to convert it to mesh.

Comment: it seems to suffer from some of the same problems, but this does make it much easier to manipulate. i guess i'll have to see what works best for the situation. thanks though!

Comment: Try increasing the "Steps" slider in the modifier. I've used the bare minimum here but when increased to say 32 or more, it rounds off the outer curve significantly. There are also "Render steps" but I think that's just for the display, to speed the 3D window up during construction.  When it comes down to it, curves are made up of a series of 'steps'.  The more you have, the finer the 'resolution'. Good luck with your project...

Comment: i'm trying to keep polygons to a minimum, and i can only use flat triangles. i'm exporting this to a pretty limited engine, so i can't do smooth shading either.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a 90-degree angle and use a subdivision surface set to around 2 or 3. Then click smooth in the left panel. This should create a smooth enough curve. You can use loop cuts to straighten out parts you don't want curved.

Comment: what do you mean by create a 90 degree angle? should it be a right triangle, a rectangle, and then where does it go? this post is extremely vague.

Comment: You should be looking for something like this https://imgur.com/gallery/vOPNWhk. If you add a subdivision surface it will create a curve.

Comment: that's not what i want though

Comment: How? What do you want?

Comment: i need a ramp to go around the corner, like in the picture...

Answer (score 0):

You can try something rounded like so.
[image: Rounded]

Comment: that's pretty much a staircase, i need a ramp.
also, you could reduce the amount of polygons on the far corner, all you need is one triangle.

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling you're looking for something that may not be geometrically possible (a smooth continuously sloping ramp like you are describing can't be made out of a small number of simple tris/coplanar quads).  The answers given so far have provided some pretty good options within the constraints of what can be done.  Here is one more option:

[image]

You might call this a variation on some of the answers already given.  This was created by making a helical "screw augur" as described in @Edgel3D's answer and then slicing it into a square shape using boolean modifiers with cube objects as the cutters, one for the exterior and one for the interior.

When the augur helix is sliced up this way, the exterior and interior edges are a bit "wavy", they do not describe straight lines but rather slight sine curves.  They can be straightened, although this is a bit tedious: the vertices along each edge have to be manually aligned to a line using a custom transform orientation, using the technique described in @Mentalist's answer to this question:

[Straighten Vertices Along a Line](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33525/straighten-vertices-along-a-line)

The resulting shape is a bit curious, it is composed of quadrilaterals whose vertices are not quite coplanar.  But the end result is a ramp where the distortions are spread out and therefore more or less "smooth", rather than confined to the corners of the ramp.

[image]

[image]

[image]