# How to align vertices 100% accurately?

Tags: edit-mode, mirror, coordinates

So there's a problem I'm facing every time I work with mirror modifier. When I'm shaping only half of the mesh I have troubles aligning vertices that must have '0' local coordinates.

The issue is when I'm selecting more than 1 vertex and set it coordinates to 0 here.
[image]

I get random values for each single vertex. Like this.

[image]

And so I have to set each vertex to '0' manually.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/140/599

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is likely because the vertices are not aligned. The transform panel shows the *median* location of all selected vertices; setting it to 0 will move the whole selection as a unit:

[image]

To align the vertices, *scale* them (<kbd>S</kbd>) to 0 along the axis you which them to be aligned along. So for the X axis, <kbd>S</kbd> <kbd>X</kbd> `0`:

[image]